# While getting count() of child records, how to get its parent records field as well

Tags: apex

This returns the id and the count of child records. How would I also get a TotalNumber field from its parents record as well in apex?

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
SELECT Transaction__c Id, count(Id) sum
    FROM TransactionItem__c
    WHERE Transaction__c = :transactionIds
    GROUP BY Transaction__c
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AggregateResult queries are for getting summary information (minimum, maximum, average, sums, and counts). To get individual record fields, you need a separate query:

```
Map<Id, Transaction__c> transaction = new Map<Id, Transaction__c>([
  select field1,field2,etc...
  from Transaction__c
  where id = :transactionIds
]);
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for confirming. Will use the separate query. Appreciate it!